# Drawing fixed number of graphs using par(mfrow())

Tags: r

I have the question following :

How can we divide our plots using par(mfrow()) with fixed number of subplots in one image ? e.g. I want for example to plot 10 graphs using par(mfrow=c(2,3)) but I want to have 5 in the first image and 5 in the second one, but the par(mfrow()) will divide them into 6:4.

How can we plot 5:5 instead od 6:4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call `plot.new`. Its documentation even says:

> This is [...] also useful for skipping plots when a multi-figure
> region is in use.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
for (i in 1:5) plot(i)
plot.new()
for (i in 6:10) plot(i)
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Exactly what I was looking for! :D